# Building docker image with TeXLive 2017 and latexml

Tags: git, perl, docker, latex, latexml

I am trying to make a docker image with full TeXLive 2017 and [latexml](http://dlmf.nist.gov/LaTeXML/) for compiling latex to pdf and also converting latex to html.
I believe this would be a useful tool.
Here is my dockerfile:

```
FROM debian:testing
MAINTAINER Dr Suman Khanal <suman81765@gmail.com>
LABEL updated_at '2017-07-26'
RUN apt-get update \
  && apt-get install -y gnupg git wget curl libgetopt-long-descriptive-perl libdigest-perl-md5-perl python python-pygments
WORKDIR /usr/local/src
RUN curl -sL http://mirror.utexas.edu/ctan/systems/texlive/tlnet/install-tl-unx.tar.gz | tar zxf - && mv install-tl-20* install-tl

WORKDIR install-tl
RUN echo "selected_scheme scheme-full" > profile \
  && ./install-tl -repository http://mirror.utexas.edu/ctan/systems/texlive/tlnet -profile profile
WORKDIR /
ENV PATH /usr/local/texlive/2017/bin/x86_64-linux:$PATH
RUN apt-get install -y libarchive-zip-perl \
  libfile-which-perl libimage-size-perl  \
  libio-string-perl libjson-xs-perl libtext-unidecode-perl \
  libparse-recdescent-perl liburi-perl libuuid-tiny-perl libwww-perl \
  libxml2 libxml-libxml-perl libxslt1.1 libxml-libxslt-perl  \
  imagemagick libimage-magick-perl 
RUN git clone https://github.com/brucemiller/LaTeXML.git && cd LaTeXML && perl Makefile.PL && make && make install 
CMD ["tlmgr", "--version"]
```

But its throwing this error `Build failed: The command '/bin/sh -c git clone https://github.com/brucemiller/LaTeXML.git && cd LaTeXML && perl Makefile.PL && make && make install' returned a non-zero code: 127`.
Any help where I have made mistake?

Comment: The result is published at https://github.com/sumandoc/TeXLive-2017

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing `make` executable (`apt-get install make`) so build process crashes after `perl Makefile.PL`

Comment: OK let me build it again. They say `cd` command does not work inside dockerfile. Is it true? Can that be problem in my dockerfile?

Comment: From my experience everything that works in shell, also works for dockerfile.